# What knowledge is required to integrate an API?

Tags: node.js, api

I'm trying to connect the Pwinty API to a website I'm building.

I'm many hours into a deep dive tutorial in how to build an app with Node.js. The tutorial builds servers etc manually, uses Sandman/node.js dependencies without packages run by npm (ie just using node.js modules) and is *very* complex.

I want the simplest and most effective way of connecting my website to Pwinty's API.

- What should I research and learn? Is Node.js the right language for the job?
- If so is a deep dive into Node.js necessary? Should I be focusing on npm packages? Which ones do I need?
- What are the actual concrete steps I need to take in order to connect the Pwinty API to my website? (e.g. 1. Create http/https servers, 2. Configure handlers etc..)

Resources:

[Pwinty API docs](http://pwinty.com/api/)

[Pwinty Node.js on Git](https://github.com/doodlemoonch/pwinty)

Comment: This has an example => https://www.npmjs.com/package/pwinty

Comment: I can't understand this though - this is what I need to find out. How do I obtain the knowledge to know what to do with that page?

Comment: It is not necessary to go with `Node.js`, if you are comfortable with any language listed under "**Client Libraries**" here => http://pwinty.com/api/ would do.

Comment: So if I took a course on Ruby for example, would I come out with the skills necessary to build this API?

Comment: Well it depends!.. If you are a quick grasper you will be to achieve it in a short span of time, otherwise might take a little more time.

Comment: But what I mean is, would a standard course on Ruby in theory provide you with a sufficient knowledge base to connect the Pwinty API? Or is there additional knowledge that must be sought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pwinty API is a standard REST API. You may choose to implement it in any programming language that can create http requests or has a library for doing so - basically all of them.

Some packages - such as the [pwinty library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pwinty) on npm, create methods to wrap the api, so using it is simpler, or easier to understand for some.

To implement the pwinty API in node.js using the node [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) (HTTP request library), for example to create an order according to the [pwinty api docs](http://pwinty.com/api/), you would use the following code

```
const request = require("request");

request.post({
    "url": "https://api.pwinty.com/v3.0/orders",
    "headers": {
        "X-Pwinty-MerchantId": "YourMerchantId",
        "X-Pwinty-REST-API-Key": "YourAPIKey",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "form": {
        "countryCode": "GB",
        "stateOrCounty": "Glamorgan"
        // etc
    }
}, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        // error handling
    }

    let json = JSON.parse(body);
    let address1 = json.data.address1;
})
```

Or, perhaps, using the [pwinty library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pwinty), the example they give on the README.MD is

```
var pwinty = require('../lib/pwinty')('apiKey', 'merchantId', 'https://api.pwinty.com:443');

var orderParams = {};
pwinty.createOrder(orderParams, function (err, order) {

    var photo = {
        type: "4x4",
        url: "photourl",
        copies: "2",
        sizing: "ShrinkToExactFit",
        priceToUser: "450"
    };

    pwinty.addPhotoToOrder(order.id, photo, function (err, order) {
        console.log('photo added');
    });
})
```

but frankly this library looks poorly documented and unmaintained, personally I would not use it.

Comment: This definitely fills in some blanks and your note about usage is very useful indeed.